# C# cannot convert int to string

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-entities

```
var query = from s in student
            select new ListItem
            {
                ID = s.studentId, 
                Name = s.studentName
            };
```

When I tried to execute the code I got the error

/`/Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' (studentId) to 'string' (ID).`

Is there anyway I can achieve this?

Comment: how about using `.ToString()`

Comment: I think we're missing something here. I don't see `ContactId` referenced anywhere, and unless `ListItem` not the `ListItem` I think it is, it should be `new ListItem { Value = s.studentId.ToString(), Text = s.studentName }`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try 'ToString()'?

```
var studentId = s.studentId.ToString();
var query = from s in student select new ListItem { ID = studentId, Name = s.studentName };
```

Comment: var query = from s in student
            select new ListItem
            {
                ID = s.studentId.ToString(), //Throws exception: ToString is not supported in linq to entities.
                Name = s.Name
            }; I have tried this also..

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using LINQ to Entities ToString won't work for you instead you will have to try out

`SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)s.studentId)` //since there is no overload for int

Check this out [Sql Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466166.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

create a new variable with var type and assign the value of studentid to that vaiable and use the new one in your linq

Comment: I have tried the following var query = from s in student select new ListItem { ID = s.studentId.ToString(), //Throws exception: ToString is not supported in linq to entities. Name = s.Name };

Comment: then declare your ID as string

Answer (score 0):

The [ListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.aspx) does not contain an ID property. Try using one of its constructors;

```
var query = from s in student select new ListItem(s.studentName, s.studentId.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Convert.ToString() method.....Convert.ToString(obj) doesn't need to presume the object is not null (as it is a static method on the Convert class), but instead will return String.Empty if it is null.....

```
 var query = from s in student
                        select new ListItem
                        {
                            ID = Convert.ToString(s.studentId),
                            Name = s.studentName
                        };
```